# SSD + HDD combo modern configuration

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, filesystems, combine

I am finding a lot of information about the SSD+HDD combo configuration, but everything seems outdated. I would be using it on a laptop, 500GB HDD, 64GB SSD, and 16GB RAM. I will be using Xubuntu, if that is relevant.

I was considering to use the SSD for the swap partition, or the `/boot` directory. I was not planning to use `/` at the SSD because the installation of some programs may require a lot of space out of `/home`. I am not completely sure about the location used for Docker images and other software, but I think that 64GB may not be a lot of space when installing a lot of software (I may be mistaken). I am also uncertain about the possibility of **moving** other directories out of the SSD later on, as for example `/opt`. I am also uncertain about how to **create** them in one place or another, it is probably trivial after setting it up, because I could not find any information about that.

SSD+HDD combos have been around for a while, if there is some configuration that is used as a **standard** it would be great to know about it. If there are guides or **references** that are current in their information, that would also be very helpful.

Comment: OK, I didn't tell everything. It's dual boot 128GB and 1TB. I'm quite certain the way to go is: split the SSD in two partitions. 64GB for swap partition, then 64GB for caching (as a cache for windows). It's like not having an SSD (and not worrying about disks) but it will speed up some things, especially those that I need most (or so I believe).

Answer (score 2):

This is outdated (2014) but I do not see any reason why this would not apply to what you are trying to achieve:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/519208/installing-ubuntu-on-a-ssd-and-hdd-system

They discuss which directories they keep where. Hope it helps. If anything you could always try reposting in https://askubuntu.com/.

-SirPuddles

Comment: Please don't add your user name to your answers.